# PHP relative path: can I configure it?

Tags: php, apache, relative-path

**tl;dr:** How do I make PHP interpret relative paths in include/require statement from the perspective of the current file?

This is yet another question about that old issue in PHP about relative paths. Please bear with me, as I couldn't find any solution for what I am specifically trying to do.

Consider the following directory tree and files:

```
[www]:
    index.php
    config.php
    [webroot]:
        home.php
```

`index.php` requires `home.php`, found inside `webroot`:

```
require('webroot/home.php');
```

`home.php` requires `config.php`, found in the parent directory:

```
require('../config.php');
```

My problem is that this won't work in my local development environment (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / 15.10), whereas it runs flawlessly in production. Every mentioned environment is running Apache 2 and PHP 5.
Strangely, this does run locally when I run it inside my Vagrant VM (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), accessing it from the host machine. But, right now, I cannot run a VM here.

So, why do these environments behave so differently?
This makes me believe that there must be a way to change how PHP interprets relative paths. I am currently working with a 6GB+ PHP project that is written like the example above, and I really need to avoid the amount of effort that it'll take from me to rewrite every include/require statement (using `dirname(__FILE__)` or so), as well as the git merge conflicts this *might* cause.

**EDIT**: I've just remembered I actually had already asked this question here: [PHP: include inside included file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32660865/3471286)

Comment: If you have 6GB+ of PHP code, *you're doing something wrong*. Or, that code is machine generated from some compile-time template, and changing the template would change all the files anyway.

Comment: @IMSoP It's a 4 years old git project.

Comment: But how big is *the current codebase*? You don't need to rewrite all the history, so subtract the size of the `.git` folder. And even then, I doubt that there's that much actual *code*, there's presumably some images and stuff in there. The entire Linux kernel is only ~600MB unzipped (in 52 thousand files). Nonetheless, I've answered your question as posed.

Comment: (Incidentally, if you want to measure the actual size of PHP, you could use `find path/to/project -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-`; or more relevantly, how many PHP files there are: `find path/to/project -type f -name '*.php' | wc -l`)

Comment: 93M total, in 7756 files. Yes, I wouldn't have to edit every one of these 7756 files, but it would still make me work for some hours I could spare if PHP wasn't so badly designed :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can't blame this one on PHP, only on the person who relied on relative paths. Just because you/they didn't understand how those paths were being interpreted doesn't make PHP wrong to interpret them that way. (And incidentally, most modern PHP frameworks and applications have very few include paths hard-coded because class autoloading takes care of it for you.)

Comment: @IMSoP I do blame the ones who relied on relatives paths in PHP. I just can't see the reason behind why PHP is made to read relative paths the way it does in a require/include chain, and why it behaves differently sometimes (while I can't find how to configure it). I just did the `getcwd` serverside: it outputs the location of the edited file, not of the main script

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I just need to sort out one file. The problem lies there -- I need the PHP interpreter to look for relative paths from the perspective of the current file being read, not the main (first) file. It's the exact same script as production starting from same exact dir. Your dump's output is: `string(12) "/www/webroot" string(4) "/www" string(22) "/www/webroot/home.php2"`

Comment: DOC_ROOT is actually `/var/www/html`, but I'm not sure if that's related (the paths in the question are all fictitious), as I only wanted to know how to change relative path perspective. I don't know how to read the .htaccess, but I can include it in the question if you need it.

Comment: Sorry for taking long time to reply. In my fictitious structure, it points to `/www`. In my production system, it points to `/var/www/html`, and in my dev system, it's actually `/home/user/Documents/project` (which is a synced folder to a vagrant machine, who sees this as `/var/www/html` as well).

Answer (score 5):

The path used to resolve relative URLs like this is configured by [the `include_path` configuration option](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) which has a dedicated function for setting it at runtime: [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).

Note that the set of paths to search may include `.`, representing the "current working directory", which can be set with [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) and read with [`getcwd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php). You may also need to change this to make explicitly relative paths like `./foo.php` and `../foo.php` to work.

(I was going to recommend you used `__DIR__` or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead, but you mention that you don't want to rewrite existing code. I would still recommend to anyone else reading this to make explicit in each include where paths are relative to, to avoid odd bugs and potential security holes with the dynamic base.)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. I just tried adding `include_path="."` to the php.ini, and adding a `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ".");` to the beggining of a crucial file in the project, but it still gives me the same error. Do you think I am missing something?

Comment: @GuiImamura Have you tried echoing out `getcwd()`? `.` doesn't mean the same thing as `__DIR__`, it's not relative to the file where the include is written; it is the "current working directory", like you would have when navigating with `cd` in a shell.

Comment: `getcwd()` gives me the root of project, not the path to the file that I wrote `getcwd` into. Is there a way I can change this to the current file everytime I include/require?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you set the working directory with `chdir`. However, it would be worth checking what the settings are on the working server (`echo get_include_path()` and `echo getcwd()`), and making things match that, because unless there is magic happening there to keep changing working dir, you shouldn't need magic on your new server either.

Comment: `chdir` works just as `dirname(__FILE__)`. I think there's no way to make it default for every include/require, or is there any?

Comment: @GuiImamura Like I say, either your working server is already doing such a default, or you don't need a way of doing it. All you need to do is match the configuration between the two servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override existing functionality in place you need to either install an [external library](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) or use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php). Both are extra work. I'm guessing that installing an extra library probably isn't even an option.

You could try adding the paths to those folders using [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).

Or you could add a global variable and several global functions like below, for all the require and include overloads, but you would still have to do a find/replace through the whole project for instances of include, require, include_once, require_once... and replace them with "include_rel"...

```
$include_rel_path = '.';

function include_rel($path){
    global $include_rel_path;

    $my_path = $include_rel_path;

    //TODO maybe need to check for drive letters?
    if(strpos($path, '/') === 0) { //absolutepath
        $include_rel_path = preg_replace('/\/[^\/]*$/','',$path);
        include($path);
    } else { //relative path
        $include_rel_path .= preg_replace('/\/[^\/]*$/','',$path);
        include($my_path.'/'.$path);
    }
    $include_rel_path = $my_path;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 $path .= "/Folder/File.php";
 include_once($path);
?>
```

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). if PHP is run as an Apache module then .htaccess file to the path to your `config.php` file and any PHP file accessed will automatically have the contents of the config file prepended to it.

For `.htaccess`:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /full/path/to/file/config.php
```

If your server is using CGI then set this directive in your php.ini or Keep in mind this ONLY will work on a server where If PHP is run as a CGI you need to add edit it in your `php.ini` file or put it inside a `.user.ini` file just without the `php_value` part.

```
auto_prepend_file /full/path/to/file/config.php
```

In `Nginx` you could add this line to server configuration inside `location ~ \.php$`

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/full/path/to/file/config.php";
```

Let me know if doesn't resolve your problem.

Comment: I believe this would solve my problem, if it works. Please explain a bit further: I just have to create a `.htaccess` in rootdir (`www`) and put that first code into it?

Comment: Thank you for your input, but it still gives me the same error. Using apache2 without CGI.

Comment: May be some settings problem, is .htaccess working properly

Answer (score -1):

index.php:

```
chdir('webroot');
require_once('home.php');
```

Comment: Hi. I need a way to default it in the PHP interpreter, so I don't have to change hundreds of lines of code, and it also needs to `chdir` back to where it was after the include/require.

Comment: Did that not work?  If the point of entry of the app is usually home.php, then echo getcwd() from home.php would read /path/to/webroot .