# Flysystem v3: issue using Local adapter

Tags: php, flysystem

I'm a new user of Flysystem.

To get started I'm trying to write files within an existing php app using the Local adapter.

I'm setting up the adapter / file system using this approach:

```
$adapter = new LocalFilesystemAdapter('/');
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
```

When I come to write out the files I'm submitting this instruction:

```
filesystem->write('/var/www/html/public_html/files/'.$file_name, $file_content);
```

However this generates no errors, but also no saved file.

I traced the execution of the write, and it turns out when it comes to the `@file_put_contents` step (line 123 of `LocalFileSystemAdapter.php`) the path that is supplied is `var/www/html/public_html/files/'.$file_name` (i.e. what was supplied, but missing the opening `/`).

The `file_put_contents` instruction is therefore writing the output to a **relative path**, rather than to the path provided / required.

How do I change things so that Flysystem writes to the path required?

Thanks in advance for whatever guidance you can offer.
Attempts to write files fail because the write-path is incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP relative path: can I configure it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272966/php-relative-path-can-i-configure-it) - Relative paths shouldn't be a problem for a local file-system as they are resolved to their absolute path in PHP against the current working directory of the PHP process which you can control with `chdir()`, see the link. And IIRC consult the manual of Flysystem, it has a method for that, too. However, if that jacket does not suit you, why wear it? Only it's fashion, it does not mean your look must benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks for the thought - unfortunately that's not the issue.
It appears that Flysystem is deliberately stripping leading and trailing `/` characters from the path, and then adding back a `prefix` - I think the issue is that on my system the prefix is being set to "" and hence the relative paths.
In the short term I've fixed things by changing that part of my code to use relative paths, but it is not a good long term solution.

Comment: Naturally, it's not the issue. Just use it as announced, otherwise configure it appropriately: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-local-driver — for the high level picture. And this for the low level: https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/local/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr you're not supposed to provide full path when writing, you're using Flysystem incorrectly.

---

Flysystem is a **filesystem abstraction layer** (it abstracts away details of "how" and "where" to store data.) To have proper separation of concerns in your code, you want your code NOT to know where the data is exactly stored (what's the location, what's the medium etc… should you ever want to switch to a different storage.)

When writing a file, your code should be oblivious to the adapter you're trying to use. If you say, one day, decide to switch to the cloud, in theory switching will be as easy as changing the filesystem's adapter somewhere in the configuration – you won't have to make any changes to your code.

By design, Flysystem operates on *file keys* (the first parameter of the `write` method.) To write a file you're supposed to:

```
// configure where to store your data
$adapter = new LocalFilesystemAdapter('/var/www/html/public_html/files');

// instantiate the abstraction layer
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);

// store the data using the abstraction
$filesystem->write('test.txt', 'file contents');
```

This will create a file called `test.txt` in the `/var/www/html/public_html/files` directory.

Your *file keys* can also contain "directories":

```
$filesystem->write('textfiles/test.txt', 'file contents');
```

This would create a file called `test.txt` in the `/var/www/html/public_html/files/textfiles` directory. Try it!

If you decide to use, i.e. `AwsS3V3Adapter`, Flysystem would create `textfiles/test.txt` file in your AWS bucket.

To read the created file, you have to use the same *file key* used to write the file:

```
echo $filesystem->read('file.txt');
```

---

Extra tip: you can have multiple sources defined, i.e.

- keep user thumbnails on your webserver
- keep invoices inside an AWS S3 bucket
- in your test suite you can use the "in memory" store

---

References:

- [Flysystem documentation page](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/)
- [Flysystem adapters](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/local/)